# CSS3 Gradient repeating

Tags: css

I'm trying to implement a diagonal CSS3 gradient that goes from black in the upper left corner to dark gray in the bottom right corner.

Something like:

```
body {
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, black, darkgray 80%, gray);
}
```

Instead of it being shown as I intended, it just repeats over and over every couple lines down the page horizontally. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We need the corresponding selector and html.  See http://jsfiddle.net/H9AUE/

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue.  Can you reproduce it in a simple html page.

Comment: check the height  of body

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The body has no height; you're only seeing the background from the 8px of top/bottom margin (which is always transparent).

If you want your gradient to fill the viewport, set a height of 100% on **both** `<html>` & `<body>`

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: linear-gradient(orange, red, yellow);
    margin: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JUtuJ/1/